# new to play! Having trouble with: Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation

Tags: jpa, model, playframework

new to play and just trying to follow the video on: http://www.playframework.org/

I'm coming so far that i want to create the list of tasks after creating the Task-class. I when i reload i get this error:

"UsupportedOperationException occured : Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation."

I'm using Eclipse. Also note that i have changed tasks to be persons in:

My Person model/class-defination in Person.java

```
    package models;

    import play.*;
    import play.db.jpa.*;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Person extends Model{
        public String title;
        public boolean done;

        public Person(String title){
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
```

And application.java:

```
    package controllers;

    import play.*;
    import play.mvc.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import models.*;

    public class Application extends Controller {

        public static void index() {
            List persons = Person.find("order by id desc").fetch();
            render(persons);
        }
    }
```

The error is connected with this line: 
        List persons = Person.find("order by id desc").fetch();

Comment: Resolved! Was missing a @Entity -tag with the class

Comment: Could you validate an answer please? Question is still marked as "unanswered"

Answer (score 5):

Add @Entity to the top of the model class.

Answer (score 1):

And let's be clear, use the Javax Entity annotation and not Hibernate's! As suggested in the official documentation!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before add @Entity before your Model class.

Within your example the Person class would look like that:

```
package models;

import play.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class Person extends Model{
    public String title;
    public boolean done;

    public Person(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```